# Can you have a drupal 7 site without an anonymous user

Tags: drupal-7

Looking for a way to restrict access to development and test sites. Currently, our configuration is:

productionsite.com

productionsite.com/testsite

productionsite.com/dev

Each environment is a complete drupal 7 site with it's own database.

We were thinking (maybe not correctly) that if we could remove the anonymous user on the test and dev sites, then in order to view or edit the sites you would be forced to login.

Thanks for any help

Linux
latest apache server
latest PHP
latest MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

Drupal requires an anonymous user, you won't get around that without some serious changes to the core code.

However, you can edit your site's permissions so that the anonymous user has no privileges to access content which effectively does the same thing.

If you remove the anonymous user from the database you'll probably find you can't login any more, or more to the point, you can't *stay* logged in when you get past the user login form.

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous user is important and removing it is not recommended as it can break the site.

[This entry on Drupal.org talks about why it is not good to remove the anonymous user(0)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1029506) and how to try to fix it if it happens.

In agreement to lock down the anonymous user as much as possible and then to also re-review user permissions as new modules and features are added. New permissions can be added which need further restricted as new modules are installed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you need to put your test and dev sites into maintenance mode. From the administration section go to **Configuration >> Maintenance mode**, there you can set a message that users need to login to access the site. A good idea is to also include the login page links in the text as well; i.e. productionsite.com/testsite/user and production site.com/dev/user respectively.